# AWS IOS SDK v2.0: How do I get all the folders within a bucket, and then pull all the files from said folders?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It looks like AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest requires a URL. You can append a bucket, but I don't see an option for appending anything like a prefix. That said, I'd like to be able to pull down all the folders given a bucket name, and then pull the items from said folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically Amazon S3 does not have a concept of "directories". If you have three objects with the following keys, `abc/01.test`, `abc/02.test`, and `abc/03.test`, the AWS Management Console shows a "directory" called `abc`, and in that directory, you find `01.test`, `02.test`, and `03.test`.

You can set `/` to the [`delimiter`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3ListObjectsRequest.html#//api/name/delimiter) property and call [`- listObjects:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/listObjects:). Look at the [`commonPrefixes`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3ListObjectsOutput.html#//api/name/commonPrefixes) to get the list of "directories". For the above example, `commonPrefixes` should be an array that contains `abc`.

Then you can set [`prefix`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3ListObjectsRequest.html#//api/name/prefix) to `abc/` and call `- listObjects:` again to get the list of objects under the "directory". In the above example, it should return `abc/01.test`, `abc/02.test`, and `abc/03.test`.

For each object, you can call [`- download:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3TransferManager.html#//api/name/download:) with the given [`key`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetObjectRequest.html#//api/name/key). (`AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` is a child of `AWSS3GetObjectRequest`).